# gtklib not found after installing "gtk-chtheme"?

Tags: macos, gtk2, xquartz

I'v installed *gtk+* and run some programs well under *X11* on *OSX El Capitan*. Program looks ugly, so I installed *gtk-chtheme*.

Now I can't run my program and get this error:

> Fatal error: cannot load shared library dlllablgtk2
>   Reason: dlopen(/Users/mac/.opam/system/lib/stublibs/dlllablgtk2.so, 138): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.0.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Users/mac/.opam/system/lib/stublibs/dlllablgtk2.so
>     Reason: image not found

Comment: Do you have **dlllablgtk2.so**?

Comment: Yes, "$ cd /Users/mac/.opam/system/lib/stublibs/dlllablgtk2.so"